Unable to restrict a query parameter top be passed in retrofit URL if it has empty value
I'm calling an API but here some values are empty and optional so I want to remove them from the URL.
 @GET("entriesAcceptance/v${Constants.API_VERSION}/param1/{param1Value}/param2/{param2Value}/entries?")
suspend fun getEntries(
    @Path("param1") param1Value: String,
    @Path("param2") param2Value: String,
    @Query("firstName") firstName: String
    @Query("lastName") lastName: String
): EntriesResponse

Here lastName is empty and but still it's getting passed in the url. I just want it not to be passed if it doesn't have any value. Currently URL gets printed as
entriesAcceptance/v1/param1/XXX/param2/XX/entries?&firstName=VULCANO&lastName=

It would be great help if you can help me resolve it. I tried to use @QueryMap but it does not work with String.

To achieve the desired behavior You can use null default values and adjust your method to handle nulls by excluding them from the query.

Change the lastName parameter to be nullable with a default value of null.
Use an inline if condition to include lastName only if it is not null or empty.

Here’s the modified code:
@GET("entriesAcceptance/v${Constants.API_VERSION}/param1/{param1Value}/param2/{param2Value}/entries?")
suspend fun getEntries(
    @Path("param1Value") param1Value: String,
    @Path("param2Value") param2Value: String,
    @Query("firstName") firstName: String,
    @Query("lastName") lastName: String? = null
): EntriesResponse

If you need to ensure that empty strings are treated as null, you can handle this logic before making the API call. For example:
val lastNameValue: String? = if (lastName.isNullOrEmpty()) null else lastName

val response = apiService.getEntries(
    param1Value = "XXX",
    param2Value = "XX",
    firstName = "VULCANO",
    lastName = lastNameValue
)


Now it gets passed as null in the API. I just want to remove it from URL if it doesn't have any value.

The retrofit ignores the null parameters while assembling the request. So the params with null value shouldn't be part of the URL.
The official docs show that query params with null values are ignored.
https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/http/Query.html

Make it as lastName params as nullable in the function. Call the function based on the values.
Pass null in kotlin
@Query("lastName") lastName: String? = null


It does not work. Still it gets passed in the url

if last name is empty, you should call like this getEntries(
param1Value = "XXX",
param2Value = "XX",
firstName = "VULCANO")
